# Check if $f^i(x), i\in \{1,2,3,4\}$ satisfies closure, commutative properties.

Tags: function-and-relation-composition

Given $f(x)=\frac{1+x}{1-x},\,x\neq -1,0,1,$ find:
(a) Compute the composition $f^2, f^3, f^4.$ On the basis of your findings, what are $f^{10}, f^{100}?$
(b) Let $S$ be the set of distinct functions found in part (a). List the elements of $S,$ show $S$ is closed under composition, make a Cayley table for $S.$
(c) Show that composition is a commutative operation on $S,$ there is an identity element in $S,$ and every element of $S$ has an inverse in $S.$

---

(a) $f^2= \frac{1+\frac{1+x}{1-x}}{1-\frac{1+x}{1-x}}=-1/x.$
$f^3= -\frac1{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} = \frac{x-1}{1+x}.$
$f^4= \frac{\frac{1+x}{1-x}
-1}{1+\frac{1+x}{1-x}} = \frac{1+x-1+x}{1+x+1-x}= \frac{2x}{2}=x.$
$f^5=\frac{1+x}{1-x}.$

So, the operation of function composition yields a cycle of order $4$: 
$f(x)=\frac{1+x}{1-x}, f^2(x)=-1/x,
f^3(x)= \frac{x-1}{1+x}, f^4(x)=x, \cdots$

Hence, $f^{10}= f^2= -1/x, f^{100}=x.$

(b) Let the composition be denoted by $\circ.$
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
\hline
\circ & f^1= \frac{1+x}{1-x}
 & f^2 = -1/x & f^3 = \frac{x-1}{1+x} & f^4= x\\
\hline
f^1 & f^2 & f^3
&f^4& f^1\\
\hline
f^2 &f^3&f^4&f^1& f^2\\
\hline
f^3 &f^4&f^1&f^2&f^3\\
\hline
f^4 &f^1&f^2&f^3&f^4\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Not clear how to show, except by taking all possible compositions $x\circ y$ of any two elements: $x, y\in S,$  that $S$ is closed under composition.

(c) As stated among the methods [here](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/ways-to-show-a-group-is-abelian), the easiest method is to show if the group is cyclic. Here, all elements generate the group.

Only by examination of the table, can state $f_4$ is the identity element of $S.$

Although, found while constructing the Cayley table, but is there an easy way to show that every element has an inverse in the given set, under the operation of function composition?

I found that $(f^1)^{-1}= f^3,$ and vice-versa. Inverse of $f^2, f^1$ is itself.

Have a related doubt: why associative property check was not asked?

Comment: According the related doubt: From the definition the associative property follows immediately.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe So, that is true by definition.